# Bash Script multi conditional fails

Tags: bash, shell

In this Bash Shell script I like to check if the length of the string is zero. In that case the script should echo an error message and exit.

```
dbname="ssss"
dbuser=""

if [ -z "$dbname"]
then
        echo "DB name is not specified!"
        exit
fi

if [ -z "$dbuser"]
then
        echo "DB user is not specified!"
        exit
fi
```

If dbname is "" it works as expected. But if it has some value and I was expecting to see it exit at the next conditional, I get this error message:

```
Script.sh: line 4: [: missing `]'
DB user is not specified!
```

Why the error message?

Comment: You are working too hard.  Try ${dbname:?DB name is not specified}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[ -z "$dbuser"]
```

should be

```
[ -z "$dbuser" ]
# note: ------^
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space after the quotes.

```
if [ -z "$dbuser"]
```

If `$dbuser` is empty, it looks like this to bash, which is valid because it has a space:

```
if [ -z ]
```

When `$dbuser` is populated, the `]` will be attached to the string, and will think the `]` is part of the string:

```
if [ -z theuser]
```

To fix this, just add a space after your second double quote:

```
if [ -z "$dbuser" ]
```

Now, it'll get translated as the following, and everything is fine:

```
if [ -z theuser ]
```